# How does the inner function in a HOC get the props

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

I'm just getting my head around using `HOC` in `React`, one thing that is confusing me slightly is, how does my inner function in this example gain access to `props` as an argument?

```
const withProps = Component => (
  props => {
    return <Component {...props}/>
  }
)

export default withProps
```

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to achieve, how you would want to call this HOC and why you wrote the code like it is (are you following a tutorial / blog post / ...?). Otherwise, you risk downvotes because your question is not answerable.

Comment: clear your use case please

Comment: This is a trivial example that doesn't have any functional purpose, it simply passes props along - i've used this simple example to help illustrate my question.

Comment: @Samuel then please update your question and describe what exactly you want to achieve with this code and how the client code is supposed to call it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add more to what @AliAnarkali said, a HOC returns you a component so when you write like

```
const EnhancedApp = withProps(App);
```

EnhancedApp is basically

```
  const EnhancedApp = props => {
    return <Component {...props}/>
  }
```

which a functional component and when you render EnhancedApp like

```
<EnhancedApp onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.value} />
```

It is similar to how a functional component receives onChange and value as props and hence in an HOC, the inner function gets the props like this.

Comment: Thanks you, this really helped break it down in my head!

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I am missing AliAnarkali thread. Can you repeat what he said?