# Exporting default statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to understand the export and import statement in React (Might involve the use of HOC)

So I have a higher component known as `withclass.js` like this

```
import React from 'react';

const withClass = (WrappedComponent, ClassName) => {
   console.log(WrappedComponent)
console.log(ClassName)
  return (props) => (
    <div className={ClassName}>
      <WrappedComponent />
    </div>
  )
}

export default withClass;
```

And inside our App.js, we do something like this

```
import withClass from '../hoc/withclass.js';
import classes from './App.css';
        class App extends Component {
        //some code here
    //------ include render and return

export default withClass(App, classes.App);
```

Now, In Export statement I understand that he is passing two parameters which our withClass function requires as parameters but shouldn't **he import something in `withclass.js`? How does our `withclass.js` receive those arguments?**

**Also, how does our return function (in withclass.js) get access to props here? (for example we passed props as an argument to our return function in withclass.js)?**

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50015842/react-hoc-props/50018022?noredirect=1#comment87052916_50018022

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Your answer there somewhat felt incomplete to me.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't quite clear what you are asking for but regarding passing the argument you can do something like shown below. If I can get a little more explanation, I will update my answer.

```
 import withClass from '../hoc/withclass.js';
            class App extends Component {
            //some code here
        //------
      return (
        <Aux>
          <button onClick={this.showPersonTrueHandler}>Show Persons </button>
          <Ccockpit
          coatiitle = {this.props.title}
          cocPersonState = {this.state.showPerson}
          cocperson = {this.state.person.length}
          toggler = {this.togglerPersonHandler} />
          {person}
          </Aux>
         )
       }
    }
    export default withClass((parameter1, parameter2)=>{
    //perform any action here...
    })(App);
```

Comment: In First part of my code (`withclass.js`) he does something `const withClass = (WrappedComponent, ClassName) => { return (props) => (` How does our return function get access to props here or when did we pass argument to our return function?