# Why "this" keyword refers to passed argument?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am attaching a react code below, but my question is about basic JavaScript. I am creating a higher order component and passing a previously created component to another one as argument, and what I couldn't really understand is why "this" keyword refers to WrappedComponent? It works without problem, but that is the problem, I don't understand how it works.

Would be glad if you could explain what is happening below:

```
import React from 'react';

const LoadingHOC = (WrappedComponent) => {
    return class LoadingHOC extends React.Component{
        render() {
            return this.props.userName === "" ? "Loading..." : <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the inner function in a HOC get the props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50015842/how-does-the-inner-function-in-a-hoc-get-the-props/50018022#50018022)

Comment: `this` doesn't refer to the wrapped component, but to the HOC. You are calling the enhanced component with some props that you want to be available in the wrapped component, so  the hoc doesn't have to care about what the wrapped component needs, it just passes all his props to wrapped component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` inside the `LoadingHOC` class refers to the instance of the class.

Consider the following :

```
import React from 'react';

const LoadingHOC = (WrappedComponent) => {
    return class LoadingHOC extends React.Component{
        render() {
            return this.props.userName === "" ? "Loading..." : <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
        }
    }
}

const DummyComponent = (props) => (<div>{props.username}</div>);

const EnhancedComponent = LoadingHOC(DummyComponent);
```

`LoadingHOC(DummyComponent)` calls the `LoadingHOC` **function** that you declared and returns you the `LoadingHOC` **class** that you describe inside the function. So, doing something like :

```
<EnhancedComponent username="john"/>
```

Will result in instantiating the `LoadingHOC` class, with a `username` prop, that will be passed along to the `WrappedComponent` argument, in our case `DummyComponent`.

Hope it's clear enough to you.